# Typescript/Angular8 Check user login info before displaying the Page with async API

Tags: angular, typescript, async-await

I use ngOnInit to do some init tasks like check user infos. I'm working on an administration page where not logged in users should be redirected to the login page. My Problem is that the users API is called asynchron and the userrights are not present at the  beginning of loading the page.

What is the best practice to check user rights in ngOnInit? Can i wait for the result of asynchronous API call?

I could use it async, but what am i doing meanwhile? Maybe the page is rendered before the accountService has answered.

```
private async loadAccountInfos(idpId: string, email: string): Promise<void> {
    this.account = await this.accountService.getAccount(idpId, email);
    this.accountAuthorization = await this.accountService.GetUserAuthorizationInfo();
  }
```

Comment: Why don't you try to store token in local storage and once you called any API then at that time send token along with parameter or header. In the API logic check whether token is expired or not. If expired then  return any flag to redirect the user to login page

Answer (score 0):

In angular you can achieve this with [route guards](https://angular.io/guide/router#preventing-unauthorized-access).

For your use case *canActivate* can be used in your guard class.
First make your promise resolve to a boolean:

```
isAuthorised(idpId: string, email: string): Promise<boolean> {
  return this.accountService.getAccount(idpId, email).then(() => {
        // make this resolve to Promise<boolean>
        return this.accountService.GetUserAuthorizationInfo();
    });
}
```

then in you *canActivate* method you can do:

```
canActivate(
  next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
  state: RouterStateSnapshot) {
  return from(this.isAuthorised('id', 'example@example.com'))
    .pipe(map(isAuth => {
      if (!isAuth) {
        // based on you boolean
        // you can either return a UrlTree for login page
        // this.router.createUrlTree();

        // or use a router to navigate to login and return false
        // this.router.navigate();
        // return false
      }
      return true;
    }));
}
```

Remember you components at that route where you place your guard won't load until guard resolves.
If false is return and you don't redirect somewhere nothing is loaded in the [router-outlet](https://angular.io/api/router/RouterOutlet)